DjangoAdmin: Use InlineModels without a parent model
I have a model (e.g. Contact with two fields, email and name). I'd like to add a custom view to Django Admin that allows for batch creation of multiple contacts. As they do not have a m2m-relationship, there is no way for me to add them as a InlineModelAdmin into another object. Is there a way to reuse the inline-code from Django admin to add a custom view for batch adding multiple contacts?
As a strating point for adding custom views I'm currently at (which simply adds a add-page under the /add/multiple path).
class ContactAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_urls(self):
        info = self.opts.app_label, self.opts.model_name
        urls = [
            path(
                "add/multiple/",
                self.admin_site.admin_view(self.add_multiple_view),
                name="%s_%s_add_multiple" % info,
            )
        ]
        return urls + super().get_urls()

    def add_multiple_view(self, request, form_url="", extra_context=None):
        return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)

